# Typeerror missing the positional arguments

Tags: python, typeerror, positional-argument

I want to open the csv file and reverse it while I read the code, replace the date with the consecutive numbers and leave it there.

```
def s(a, b):
    try:
        if a==str(userInput) and b==int(userInput):
            for line in reversed(list(open("AAPL.csv"))):
                b=[0]
                a=[]
                for bin line:
                    count=1
                    b= count
                count+=1
                a=[]
                a=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'adj_close']
                a.lower()
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return a, b

    def main():
        pass
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>test_date() 
TypeError: test_date() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'col' and 'day'
```

Comment: The error is coming from a `test_date` function which you have not shown

Answer (score 0):

The error itself means that the function **test_date** requires 2 arguments but you either passed one or none.

You need to paste in the function code to help you further.

#### A tip

You can convert the positional arguments to key arguments, which basically means adding a default value to the argument at the definition of the function, that way if the function has not been passed any args, it will work with the default values.

### Example Code

```
def greet(name="World"):
    print("Hello",name)

greet()
# Prints out "Hello World"

greet("Michael")
# Prints out "Hello Michael"
```